# how do i sort realmlist field date, just only hh:mm. the yyyy/MM/dd is not include

Tags: java, android, date, realm

I have a scheduling app which just saves day and hour for alarm/notification.
The day I save in string, and the hour (Time: `hh:mm:ss`) I saved in `Date` with dummy (`yyyy/MM/hh`).

I can find the schedule with filter day (`equalTo.("day","Sunday")`), but for the time, I can't compare current time with my date to get next schedule `greaterThan` current time in database which have dummy (yyyy/MM/hh).

Should I save my day and time in `Date` with find next date which is equal date? Example — I save with this : day in my data is `Sunday`, and current date is `Fri, 28-apr-2017`.  This means I save data is `Sun, 30-apr-2017 hh:mm:ss`. But how to getDate while I only have day and time?

Comment: It sounds to me like a job that will be a lot easier with the classes in `java.time`. Those were introduced in Java 8, but a backport for Android exists, [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). Take a look through [the turorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: Why not save the whole year-month-day-hour-minute-second for a notification?

Comment: if i want to save whole `Date`, i must find `Date` by dayOfMonth `EEE`, because in my application, users only input NameOfDay and hours, and that schedule will repeat when NameOfDay and hour is `equalTo` current day and time. and i used Realm Database, which is doesn't support with `Time` and only support Date

Comment: Still, you need to solve that problem either when you save the alarm or later when you figure out when to trigger it. Could be simpler to do it on save.

Comment: thanks bro, i have solved that problem.

Comment: You may post an answer to your own question and show us how you solved it exactly. Could be useful for others in the future. You may also accept your own answer (though you don’t getting any rep points from the answer being accepted by yourself).

Comment: i am sorry bro @OleV.V. i just confused for my choice, because i've just learn java..

Comment: Don’t worry, it was a fine discussion and not any poor question at all.